# Cancellation via Ample Line Bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I am wondering if the following argument is true:

Let $X$ be a dimension $n$ compact projective complex manifold, let $\alpha\in H^{n-1,n-1}(X,\mathbb{Q})$ be a cohomology class. If for any line bundle $L$, we have $c_1(L)\cup \alpha=0$, can I argue that $\alpha=0$?